# HTTP status 404 error when running cloned project from github on Tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have created a simple spring mvc web app and after successfully running it on the server I pushed it on github. Later I cloned this project and have imported it as a maven project as shown below (now it is already imported)

[image]

Now I am trying to run it but unfortunately I get `HTTP Status 404` error:

[image]

```
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 2 2018 14:27:55 UTC
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.13.0
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-b12
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Alexander\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Alexander\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Alexander\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\OracleHome\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Alexander\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\system32;;.]
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8089"]
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 795 ms
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:51 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8089"]
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
Nov 27, 2018 9:58:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1088 ms
```

I have seen several similar topics and it seems that everything is correct:

[image]

[image]

What I am missing?

**Update 1:**

https://github.com/AlexDev5/javaTesting

**Update 2:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiTrERL4Htw&t=12s

Comment: Can you post the project's url on Github?

Comment: I edited my question..

Comment: Is there any reason to use Servlet 2.4?

Comment: no, there isn't

Comment: I get this error: The type UserServiceImpl must implement the inherited abstract method UserService.findByUsernameAndPassword(String, String)

Comment: I corrected that, but same happens...

Comment: Your application is incomplete, you do not bootstrap Spring  dispatcher. I suggest you to read the documentation. Also, don't put on source repository the Eclipse config files.

Comment: The screencast shows there are errors on your project. Was it the UserServiceImpl  you already fixed? BTW: how did you record the GIFs?

Comment: I have tried and created another project with the same source code and it works well, so there is not problem in it. As I guess I am missing something while cloning project. I will record a video demonstrating it as soon as I can.

Comment: @Selaron I record video with Microsoft expression encoder 4 screen capture and then I convert it to gif with https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif

Comment: I added youtube link in the question, where the whole process is shown